# Expectation of random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Somewhere I found the definition of expectation of random variable as $$E[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\,dx-\int_{-\infty}^0F(x)\,dx$$

But the definition I know is $$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\,dx$$

> My Question is  why $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\,dx-\int_{-\infty}^0F(x)\,dx$$

Comment: I wouldn't call either of those two statements a "definition". At least in orthodox Kolmogorovian probability theory the definition is $\displaystyle \operatorname{E}(X) = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\,P(d\omega).$ But there's the question of why these two characterizations of expected value are equal to each other. The short answer is integration by parts. But some details require closer atttention than what that short answer gives them. I think essentially this same question has been posted here several times. Maybe I'll find it, but maybe not at this hour. $\qquad$

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It is not a definition — at best an identity, or a proposition, but I know of nowhere where the expectation would be **introduced** as the first expression you gave.*

Assuming all is well (the expectation is well-defined, for a start, and $X$ admits a density), let us write $a=\int_{0}^\infty (1-F(x))dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x)dx$:
$$\begin{align}
a &= \int_{0}^\infty (1-F(x))dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x)dx\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty (1-\int_{-\infty}^uf(u)du)dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^u f(u)dudx\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty (1-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)du)dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)dudx\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(u)-\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)du)dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)dudx\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)dudx - \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)dudx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{(x,\infty)}(u)f(u)dudx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^0 -\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)dudx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty du\ f(u) \left(\int_{0}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{(x,\infty)}(u)dx - \int_{-\infty}^0\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)dx\right)\\
\end{align}$$
Now, it remains to observe that for any $u\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{(x,\infty)}(u)dx - \int_{-\infty}^0\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,x]}(u)dx
&=
\int_{0}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{(0,u)}(x)dx - \int_{-\infty}^0\mathbb{1}_{[u,0]}(x)dx \\
&= \begin{cases}
\int_{0}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{(0,u)}(x)dx = u& \text{ if } u> 0 \\
- \int_{-\infty}^0\mathbb{1}_{[u,0]}(x)dx = u& \text{ if } u \leq 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
&= u
\end{align}$$
so overall

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty (1-F(x))dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x)dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty du\ u f(u) = \mathbb{E}[X].
\end{align}$$

Comment: I can't see all of your answer clearly.

Comment: @Marcus Is it better now? (I tried to fix the overflow in the margin).